# How to subtract start and end date in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have start date at **03-Apr-2017** and end date **17-May-2017** and the condition is I must have 2 answers that I should truncate April answer at **30-Apr-2017** so I have (30-Apr-2017 - 03-Apr-2017) and May answer will be (17-May-2017 - 01-May-2017).

How do I solve this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: I think you want 2 rows as answer. Right?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking for how to do basic calculations on date in postgres?

Comment: Ok, Its a bit difficult for me painting the scenario, But what i want should be in Datetime format not only date

Answer (score 0):

I think the question could have been worded better, but I see what you're getting at.

## My interpretation of the question

Given two date columns, let's say **start_date** and **end_date**, you want two columns (maybe four?) describing the following two intervals:

1. The interval between the **start_date** and its end-of-month date.
2. The interval between the start-of-month date of **end_date** and the **end_date**.

So, given a **start_date** of

```
'2017-04-03'
```

and an **end_date** of

```
'2017-05-17'
```

you want a **start_date_to_month_end** range of

```
'2017-04-03 -> 2017-04-30'
```

and a **month_start_to_end_date** range of

```
'2017-05-01 -> 2017-05-17'
```

## My solution (pretty)

This postgres query (based on the column names I'm using) will give you those exact results:

```
select (to_char(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' -> ' || to_char(date_trunc('month', start_date)+'1month -1day'::interval, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) as start_date_to_month_end, (to_char(date_trunc('month', end_date), 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' -> ' || to_char(end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) as month_start_to_end_date from mytable;
```

Result:

```
 start_date_to_month_end  | month_start_to_end_date
--------------------------+--------------------------
 2017-04-03 -> 2017-04-30 | 2017-05-01 -> 2017-05-17
(1 row)
```

## Per-column solution

That was with all the pretty formatting. If you just want the code for the four simple columns (**start_date, month_end, month_start, end_date**), then:

**start_date**:

```
start_date
```

**month_end**:

```
date_trunc('month',start_date)+'1month -1day'::interval
```

**month_start**:

```
date_trunc('month',end_date)
```

**end_date**:

```
end_date
```

This is all assuming that your date range doesn't span more than a 1-month difference. If it does, this code will only produce the last day of the month for the start date, and the first day of the month for the end date (obviously).

## EDITS

- Shortened interval syntax. Thanks, Abelisto!

Comment: BTW: `'1 month -1 day'::interval`

Comment: Thanks--I knew there was a way for it to be shortened. :)

Comment: Its not exactly what i wanted. for example if startdate and end date are with in a month i can just do normal subtraction. to have single answer. i dont want to split these 2 answers in 2 seperate fields because i have the first condition been that when startdate and enddate is in same month